# Import Excel (or csv) Table with user-data as subscribers to wordpress

Tags: database, users, mysql

i have a tough problem. From an existing database with user-data I need to transfer those users as subscribers to my wordpress database.

My user-profiles have various additional custom fields that I need for my user-details.

```
login   email   first_name  last_name   institut    country_code    city    zip street  phone   country_code_person city_person zip_person  street_person   homepage    sex entry_year  student payed
```

Exactly the same columns are in my excel (or csv) sheet. 
How can I iterate through an excel sheet and transfer all the users to the database?

Since I'm fairly new to this I have no clue.
Do I do this with MySQL or any other way?

Do you have tipps or tricks for me, maybe a snippet or anything?

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: My first step would be to get your CSV into a DB. PHPMyAdmin or (if you're on a mac) Sequel Pro are good for this.

Comment: So you say, it is possible to convert a CSV to a DB file? Like a .sql? I have Sequel Pro installed. Could you maybe give me some instructions in how to do so? What are the next steps after I have that?

Comment: Connect to the DB you want to import into, choose the relavant table, go to File -> Import, locate your CSV and set the params for import (delimiters etc), hit Open. Boom! Imported.